# How to configure mysql to not time out on long running queries?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, my.cnf

I have an intense query, which is issued from a java/hibernate application, that is timing out after 3-4 minutes. Which my.cnf configurations control that behavior ? or alternatively, how can this be configured through hibernate ? Why the query takes so long is beyond the scope of this question. Thanks

Comment: What error do you get back from mysql? I'm asking because the query might be exhausting the connection memory limit, and mysql would kill it.

Comment: This depends on a few things, are there any temp tables to account for, is the query being cached, etc

Answer (score 0):

You could be hitting a timeout on InnoDB locks and need to adjust the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` parameter to ensure that queries don't get cut for holding locks too long.

It's also possible that the query is still running, but the web process that initiated it has timed out. If you can see your long-running query with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` after the fact, you will need to adjust your web server request time-out.